# Passing data from one screen to another using Navigator in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and have been following a tutorial of a world time app. He made a request to a world time API to get the time of location in a file called '`world_time.dart`' and then using the data in '`loading.dart`' file. Now when the data/time is loaded, it is passed to the home screen in '`home.dart`' using `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed`. The data is passed in the form of a `Map` and recieved in another map called `data`. But when i try doing so, there is an error saying `Expected a value of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>', but got one of type 'Null'`, although I have passed it as a map.

I know the problem would be because of different SDK versions, but i cannot get around this problem. If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it.

The code below is the `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` code:

```
void setupWorldTime() async {
    WorldTime instance = WorldTime(location: 'Karachi', url: 'Asia/Karachi', flag: 'pakistan.png');
    await instance.getTime();
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home', arguments: {
      'location': instance.location,
      'flag': instance.flag,
      'time': instance.time,
    });
  }
```

Below here is the code where I recieve the data in '`home.dart`' ( just for context, I have declared data as a map before ) :

```
data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
```

This is the line where I am getting the error, along with a stack of hundereds of lines repeating:

```
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5068:5                                [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5242:11                               [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5062:5                                mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3971:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3708:18                               updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6435:14                               mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3971:15                               inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3708:18                               updateChild
```

This is home.dart:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  Map data = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');
          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.edit_location),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is loading.dart:

```
class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {

  void setupWorldTime() async {
    WorldTime instance = WorldTime(location: 'Karachi', url: 'Asia/Karachi', flag: 'pakistan.png');
    await instance.getTime();
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home', arguments: {
      'location': instance.location,
      'flag': instance.flag,
      'time': instance.time,
    });
  }


  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    setupWorldTime();
  }
.
.
.
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without the complete code. Would you be able to [edit] your question with more code while still keeping the post minimal?

Comment: Should I post the whole code as it is not very long, because i don't exactly know what should be excluded

Comment: what is your initial route ?

Comment: The Loading page, 'loading.dart'

Comment: for you reason you are getting null instead of map. is it possible you are not passing the map from different route while navigating to the `/home`.

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh is that not a map where i used Navigator.pushReplacementNamed? The arguments area?

Comment: It will be easy if you could include sample home route widget that will reproduce the same error.

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh I have edited the question, you can check that

Comment: I aml not able to find the issue from current snippet, you can create a dartpad link, that might help

Comment: I'll do so and share it here when I've made it

Answer (score 0):

It happens because You don't have any arguments for the first time. Your logic is OK ( you get some data and push another screen with this data ) but you didn't manage no data situation ( as I understand /home is the first screen in your app ).

There is the easier way to solve your problem Just manage "no data" state.
Just replace.

```
data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
```

with:

```
data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map? ?? {};
```

So now, if you don't have any arguments ( for example when you show /home for the first time, you will have default value )

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll definitely try this, if it doesn't work I'll reach out again

Comment: That worked. I don't see the red screen of DOOM now on the loading page. Thanks for the help, but can you explain how this works?

Comment: Nevermind, when i try to use the data in a widget, the ErrorWidget is being loaded instead of the Loading widget. The data is getting passed to the home screen as it is displaying the location and time

Comment: "explain how this works?" When you try to get arguments from ModalRoute you work with nullable type ( maybe data is here, maybe data doesn't exist ). So you should to check it ( my examples shows how ) and use default data when arguments is null. "when i try to use the data in a widget, the ErrorWidget is being loaded instead of the Loading widget" There is an another reason it happens, I don't know why, because I didn't see full source code.

Comment: Is there a way i can send you the full project?

Comment: because the problem is that, when used ur line of ModalRoute code, it first uses the default value, which is an empty map. but then it does get all the data which I'm trying to send when I print the data

Comment: It's just stack overflow, I can help you with little problem such as that, but all project is too much for quick answers :)

Comment: That's true. Although I am having issue with thhe app, it does run fine, just that when i run the app multiple times, that's when the issue occurs, not when it is run for the first time. Anyway, Thanks for the help!! :))